# AJAX using Jquery not working across JSP pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am developing a dynamic web application using the following technologies on Eclipse Luna : JSP for server-side scripting, Apache Tomcat v7.0, Oracle 11g as my database and Jquery.

Below is my first .jsp page which is an elementary registration page :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="ValidateRegister.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Welcome</title>
</head>

<body>

<%@include file="Home.jsp" %> <br/>

<div id="form">

<form id="login" action="RegisterProcess.jsp" method="post" name="login">  
    <table>
        <tr><td>User Name</td><td><input type="text" name="uname"/><br/></td><td><p id="unamecheck"></p></td></tr>  
        <tr><td>Email ID</td><td><input type="text" name="uemail"/><br/></td><td></td></tr>  
        <tr><td>Password</td><td><input type="password" name="upass" /><br/></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Register"/></td><td></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This page gathers user credentials and on form submission the following javascript is triggered:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {  
                $('#submit').click(function() {
                    var result=validateForm();
                    if(result===false)
                        return result;
                    else
                         checkUsername();
                          });}
                        );

            function validateForm()
            {       
               //does usual validation like empty string etc..
            }

            function checkUsername()
            {
                $.ajax(
                {
                    url:"RegisterProcess.jsp",
                    data:$("#login").serialize(),
                    type:"post",
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                     $("#unamecheck").text(data);
                        },
                    error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                        alert( "Sorry, there was a problem!" + status + errorThrown);
                        console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                        console.log( "Status: " + status );
                        console.dir( xhr );
                    },
                    complete:function(xhr,status)
                    {
                        alert( "The request is complete!" );
                    }

                });
            }
```

The jsp page being referenced is :

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"      "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Processing</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <%@page import="bean.RegisterDao"%>  

    <jsp:useBean id="obj" class="bean.User"/>  

    <jsp:setProperty name="obj" property="*"/>  

    <%  
        final int status=RegisterDao.register(obj);  
        if(status>0)
            out.print("You are successfully registered");  
        else
            out.print("Username already exists!");
        %> 

    </body>
    </html>
```

When I press submit the form, I get the alert message :"Sorry, there was a problem!error" followed by "The request is complete!" and then I'm redirected to the page RegisterProcess.jsp, which outputs the correct thing :"Username already exists" or "Registration successful".

I have used Firebug to debug but could not decipher much. Any help would be much appreciated as I could not find any similar question been asked previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be confused about what the `$.ajax` call is actually doing. AJAX is a technology that allows browsers to make asynchronous HTTP calls to resources without requiring the entire browser page to be loaded. What you're doing in your `$.ajax` call is asking for the browser to submit the data from your form to the URL, `RegisterProcess.jsp`, and then to process the result in some way.

By specifying the data type of `json` in your `$.ajax` call, you're asking jQuery to treat the response from the server as a JSON object, but the `RegisterProcess.jsp` page renders as HTML. Therefore, the `$.ajax` call interprets the response as an error and displays the message accordingly.

The reason you're subsequently redirected to `RegisterProcess.jsp` in your browser is that you don't prevent the default submission of the registration form. One way of doing that is to issue a `preventDefault()` on the incoming event, or return false from your event handler.

Restructure your code so that you submit an `$.ajax` request to a resource that returns JSON, or remove the `json` data type specifier from the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot! I subsequently followed your solution and made a couple of changes. I removed the 'dataType:"json"' line and returned false for my on submit method.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how your form is set up. Upon submission, your form makes a POST to RegisterProcess.jsp here:

```
<form id="login" action="RegisterProcess.jsp" method="post" name="login">
```

Additionally, you're making a second POST using AJAX whenever the submit button is being pressed. More than likely, you've got a race condition.

The form's POST is completing first and issuing a redirect, which interrupts your AJAX's POST in JavaScript. I'll bet that if you look at what error is being thrown, it will be some form of interrupt exception.

Do you want to redirect your user to RegisterProcess.jsp? If not, remove the action and method from your `<form>` and let your AJAX call do the verifying.

Is the user supposed to be redirected to ReigsterProcess.jsp? If so, change your form to this and remove your AJAX call:

```
<form id="login" name="login" action="RegisterProcess.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

When clicking submit, now the form will first look for a true/false return from `validateForm()` before submitting the POST and redirecting to RegisterProcess.jsp.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the valuable insight! I fixed the error by making two changes:- 1)changed the onsubmit to return false always and 2)removed the dataType from the $.ajax() method.